# Best way for String sanitization PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection, sanitization

what is the best way to sanitize this STRING to prevent SQL Injection?

```
$order_by_str = 'dest ASC';
```

EDIT

```
$whitelist = array('start','target','exec');

    if ( in_array( $order_by, $whitelist ) ) {
  $order_by_str = $order_by;
} else {
  $order_by_str = 'start';
}
```

I used now this, it seems to work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Are you even taking in user input? I'm curious why you're worrying about sanitizing a regular string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given answers don't answer the question.

**Although there is no way for the general purpose "string sanitization"**, one may notice that the given string is a very special one.
And the only way to sanitize it is *whitelisting.*

A best way to sanitize this string would be to have both parts separated and then both checked against whitelist.

So, instead of having this string whole, I'd have it in 2 variables, `$_GET['orderby']` and `$_GET['dir']`.
And so the code would be

```
$allowed = array("dest","foo","whatever");
$key     = array_search($_GET['orderby'], $allowed));
$orderby = $allowed[$key];

$dir     = $_GET['dir'] == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'; 

$query   = "SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY $orderby $dir";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$order_by_str = mysql_real_escape_string('dest ASC');
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!!!

Comment: no i recieve also an error if put an "'" behind the Statement and recieve an MySQL Error

Comment: post the script you are using

Comment: this is NOT what he is looking for and it doesn't sanitize anything.